# Use iterator in function in function parameter

Tags: python

I was trying to create some code that can solve problems with sums.
For example, if you want to take the sum of 4*i for all values of i from 3, 109, I want this code to be able to do that. However, it should also be able to deal with more complicated things than just multiplication. See a sample of what I want to do below

```
from typing import Callable

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass 

    def function_sum(self, lower_bound: int, upper_bound: int, function: Callable, *args):
        return sum((function(*args) for i in range(lower_bound, upper_bound+1)))


print(MyClass().function_sum(1, 10, lambda x: x*i, 1))
```

Is there a way to use the iterable i which is used inside the function, as a part of the function in the parameter, without forcing i to be a parameter?

```
from typing import Callable

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass 

    def function_sum(self, lower_bound: int, upper_bound: int, func: Callable, *args):
        # i is forced to be a parameter in function
        return sum((func(*args, i) for i in range(lower_bound, upper_bound+1)))


print(MyClass().function_sum(1, 10, lambda x: x*i, 1))
```

Comment: No. `i` is a variable local to the generator expression. It does not exist outside of it.

Comment: Also, you're misusing the terms iterator and iterable. Those are protocols that an _object_ can implement, not special names for the variable being bound in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reasonable way to do this; functions bind their scope at definition time, based on where they're defined, not called. Python doesn't directly support swapping out scopes like that.

You typically don't *want* to do this anyway, as it's a truly terrible design. Think about it: Even if this works, it requires the *caller* of the function to have detailed knowledge of the names and types of (some) local variables in the *callee*. What if the callee changed the name of the iteration variable from `i` to `j` (maybe `i` was being used for something else)? Now *every* caller that relied on it has to change. It ends up ridiculously tightly coupled (a bad thing) to no real benefit, since, if the function being called imposes the proper requirements on the callable passed, it can safely pass the argument by itself anyway (as your fixed code would demonstrate, if the `lambda` were properly defined as `lambda x,i: x*i`).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest having the `func` *only* take `i` as a parameter, and skip the `*args` thing entirely in favor of just binding that information inside `func`:

```
from typing import Callable


def function_sum(lower_bound: int, upper_bound: int, func: Callable[[int], int]) -> int:
    return sum(func(i) for i in range(lower_bound, upper_bound+1))


print(function_sum(1, 10, lambda i: 4*i))
```

In general, any value that a function needs to get from its caller should be passed into it as a parameter; this is the reason that parameters exist.

The `x` value is not being supplied by `func`'s caller (`function_sum`), though, it's being supplied at the point where `func` is defined -- so that's the value that *doesn't* need to be a parameter, and can simply be defined as part of the function body (in this case `4*i`, as opposed to making `x` a parameter, having the body be `x*i`, and then passing `4` into `function_sum` to in turn pass to `func`).